# Entity Framework error: The field X is required

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
        [Key] 
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public float Quantity { get; set; } 
}
```

and I'm using the following code to update the property `Quantity`:

```
  Foo f = new Foo {ID = 2, Quantity = 10}; // Updated object  

  DbSet dbSet = this.Set(f.GetType());
  dbSet.Attach(f);
  var be = Entry(f);
  be.Property("Quantity").IsModified = true;

  DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

However, the code produces an exception like this:

> "The field 'Name' is required"

As far as I know the last piece of code should only update the field `Quantity` but it is taking into account the field `Name` as well.

I could avoid this error by taking the object before the update

```
Foo f = DBContext.Foos.Single<Foo>( x => x.ID == 2);
f.Quantity = 10; 
DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

but I think that is not a good option because it will spend two database accesses.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ok. The only problem is the EF validation process that checks all properties (also the unchanged properties). So, if you set Name, EF will generate a query without Name in SET clause.

I mean, if you run this code

```
Foo f = new Foo {ID = 2, Quantity = 10, Name = "Don't care"}; // Updated object  

DbSet dbSet = this.Set(f.GetType());
dbSet.Attach(f);
var be = Entry(f);
be.Property("Quantity").IsModified = true;

DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

EF will run this query

```
update [Foos]
set [Quantity] = @p0
where ([ID] = @p1)

@p0 = 10
@p1 = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1

As others have indicated, you could create a stub entity with dummy values for its required properties. However, you seem to have several classes having a `Quantity` property that you want to update this way. It would be quite a hassle to have to know all required properties of these classes.

I think a better option is to turn off validation altogether, by adding one line:

```
DBContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

just before `DBContext.SaveChanges();`.

I assume you use a context briefly, as recommended, so it won't be necessary to turn validation on again.

Not validating `Quantity` is safe. It's a non-nullable `float` so you can't ever set a null value for it inadvertently. But note that when you require other validations `[Required]`, for example a maximum value, you'd have to add these explicitly.

#### Option 2

A more advanced alternative is to override the context's `ShouldValidateEntity` method, by making it skip entities having only one modified property named "Quantity":

```
protected override bool ShouldValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry)
{
    if (entityEntry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified)
    {
        var ose = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
                     .GetObjectStateEntry(entityEntry.Entity);
        var modifiedProperties = ose.GetModifiedProperties();
        var isValidated = modifiedProperties.Count() == 1 
                       && modifiedProperties.Any(p => p == "Quantity");
        return !isValidated;
    }
    return base.ShouldValidateEntity(entityEntry);
}
```

If you want, you can make this behavior switchable as well, for example by adding some boolean property to your context.

Comment: I was having the same problem. This works, but I don't know why it fails on validation. I have many entities, and this fails only when I'm trying to change a simple boolean property on one of them, which is irrelevant to any navigation properties, *which I've also tried loading them anyway to see if the problem goes away but doesn't*. I'd love to see what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Your class contains a `Required` property, but you not populate this field on the code:

```
Foo f = new Foo {ID = 2, Quantity = 10};
```

Replace your code with something like that:

```
Foo f = new Foo {ID = 2, Name = "Define name of Foo", Quantity = 10};
```

Notice that the property `Name` is initialized with a value.

Comment: @guillaumeracicot I agree, that is the easiest solution, but, In that piece of code I do not know the name of class (I think it is a waste of resources to fetched from database), moreover I only want to update the field `Quantity`

Answer (score 0):

Although not an EF solution, you can do this very, very easily with [Drapper](https://github.com/sextondjc/Drapper).

You supply Drapper with the update statement you want to execute and it will execute it. E.g.:

```
public Foo Update(Foo foo)
{
    return _Execute(foo) ? foo : null;
}
```

Simple. Easy. Fast. No hoop jumping & you have full control.

Comment: I'd like to see the set clause.

Comment: You determine the set clause as you supply the SQL. Would be along the lines of `UPDATE Foo set Quantity = @Quantity WHERE Id = @Id` If Foo has properties for Quantity and Id they'll be passed in to your SQL statement automatically.

Comment: If you need to generate a generic update query string with dapper you need to keep two copies of the entity and generate the query only on the changed fields (Your code does not work if you try to update name). This is the entity framework.

Comment: That's exactly why my solution does work - it's NOT Entity Framework. It's an alternative to EF.

Comment: And in my solution you only need one copy of the instance. Follow the link I posted to Drapper earlier (https://github.com/sextondjc/Drapper). This solution works.

Comment: You can also have a look to this https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions . Anyway, if you need to generate a query only on changed fields you need to know what fields are changed so you can use two copies of the entity or a proxy. This is the implementation of EF and Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use the entry option. Attach will do the work for you, but it is required to add a dummy `Name` value in order to pass the EF validations

```
Foo f = new Foo {ID = 2, Name='-'}; 
DBContext.Foos.Attach(f);
f.Quantity = 10;
DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

The field `Name` won't be updated but those properties modified after the `Attach(f)` method